# AWS IoT MQTT Retry Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Testing out AWS IoT:

Assuming the QoS is set to 1 (sent at least 1 time), but the device was not able to send the message (due to connectivity problems for example).

Would the device keep on queuing up the requests until the messages are received? Or would it try for a pre-defined amount of time and then discard the message? What is the retry policy?

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html#mqtt

Comment: If you came here, maybe you'd like to come here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172177/does-aws-iot-mqtt-broker-remember-subscribed-clients-and-undelivered-messages-ac?rq=1